# program for n-queens problem only works for n<=10 even though it should work for all n

Tags: c++

The n-queens problem asks how many different ways are there to put n queens on a n-by-n board such that the queens cannot attack each other in one move. I've written a program which partially solves this problem. I say partially because my program only works for n<=10. However, I did not specify or hard-code the value 10, or any other value, in my code.

For example, my code outputs 92 solutions for 8-by-8, 352 for 9-by-9, and 724 for 10-by-10. These are the expected values as stated on the n-queens wikipedia page. However, my code outputs 1649 for 11-by-11. The expected answer is 2,680.

I really have no idea why this would occur.

```
using namespace std;

class Board{
    struct Position{
        int r;
        int c;
    };

    public:
    int size;
    vector<vector<int> > b;         
    Position pos;               
    vector<int> placements;     
    int count;                      

    Board(int s){
        size=s;
        pos.r=0;
        pos.c=0;
        for(int i=0; i<s; i++){
            b.push_back(vector<int>());
            for(int j=0; j<s; j++){
                b.at(i).push_back(0);
            }
        }
        count=0;
    }

    bool hasQueens(){
        for(int i=0; size-i>=0; i++){
            if(b[pos.r][pos.c-i]==1){
                return true;
            }

            if(pos.r-i >= 0){
                if(b[pos.r-i][pos.c-i]==1){
                    return true;
                }
            }

            if(pos.r+i < size){
                if(b[pos.r+i][pos.c-i]==1){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void placeQueen(){
        b[pos.r][pos.c]=1;
        placements.push_back(pos.r);
    }

    void backtrack(){
        pos.c--;
        b[placements[pos.c]][pos.c]=0;
        pos.r = placements[pos.c] +1;
        placements.pop_back();
        if(pos.r==size) backtrack();
    }

    bool canBacktrack(){
        if(pos.c==1 && placements[0]==size-1) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    void nextSol(){
        while(pos.c!=size){ //while the board is not filled
            if(pos.r==size && canBacktrack()){
                backtrack();
            } else if(pos.r==size && !canBacktrack()){
                break;
            }else if(!hasQueens()){
                placeQueen();
                pos.r=0;
                pos.c++;
            } else {
                pos.r++;
            }
        }
    }

    void print(){
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++){
                cout << b[i][j];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

};


int main(){

    Board board(11);
    board.print();
    while(true){
        board.nextSol();
        if(!board.canBacktrack()) break;
        cout << ++board.count << endl;
        board.backtrack();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I really have no idea why this would occur.* -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `if (b[pos.r][pos.c - i] == 1)` -- You should start to use `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access your values in the vector.  You will see that this line goes out of bounds, regardless of the size used for `Board` -- i.e. `if ( b.at(pos.r).at(pos.c - i) == 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code segfaults for me. Running it through valgrind says that there is invalid read in this line:

```
if(b[pos.r][pos.c-i]==1){
```

in function `hasQueens()`. And indeed, there are cases in which `pos.c-i` becomes negative: whenever `pos.c` is smaller than `size`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I fixed the problem by changing
`for(int i=0; size-i>=0; i++){`
to
`for(int i=0; pos.c-i>=0; i++){`

By the way, how did you find my question? Do you answer questions on stack overflow in your free time for fun?

Comment: furhtermore, how did you use valgrind to debug? Which commands did you use? I tried `valgrind --leak-check=yes myProgram.cpp`, but this only gives info about memory leaks.

Comment: I just ran `valgrind program`. By default it will warn you about uninitialized reads/writes. In your case the problem happens at the very beginning of your program, so the warning messages quickly scroll out of the terminal. Maybe redirect output to a file or use `less` to see them.

Answer (score 0):

The organization of the code is messy, I would suggest to write your boundaries out clearly instead of relying on stopping for col == 1 and r == size (which if access incorrectly can cause a segfault). Also, NQueen problem has an elegant solution with recursion, I would suggest to look into that as well.

I was able to make some changes to your program and got the expected answer for 11 x 11, however I think there are more bugs in the code. The problem lies in the backtrack() and placeQueen() function, pos.c is decremented without checking if it's greater than 0, so it can potentially go negative and crash when access. Most importantly you don't need to do push_back/pop_back on the placement vector since you know you only can place one queen on each column so it should really be fixed size. when placing queen, you can do placement[c] = r. Hope this helps.